# Retrieving data from specific multisite blog

Tags: multisite

I have a custom-built website which pulls data from WordPress.

I've included `wp-blog-header.php` in my page and it is all set, I can get my posts, featured image, titles, anything I want, wherever I want.

Now I'd like to add new languages to my website, so I've set up multisite so I can have one site for each language. How can I access information from a specific site? I'm using subfolder method, but there is no `example.com/sub/wp-blog-header.php` file to include!

Any Ideas on how to pull data of specific site on external pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`switch_to_blog()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_to_blog) function to switch the scope to a specific site and access data from that site:

```
require_once( '/path/to/wp-load.php' );
switch_to_blog( 3 );
$option = get_option( 'admin_email' );
restore_current_blog();
```

Also, you should use `wp-load.php` when using WordPress API in your own project, not `wp-blog-header.php`

Answer (score 0):

In almost the same way, you just need to set `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to the URL which you would have accessed if you were accessing a single wordpress install. Wordpress parses that variable to determine which site you are trying to get to and then sets to lok only at the relevant DB tables.